# Ant build to operate only on subdirectories

Tags: file-io, ant, ant-contrib

I'm trying to create an Ant build that will run a target in every subfolder in a folder. I need this one in particular to only run at the subfolder level, because if I run it from the top folder and tel it to include subfolders, it scrambles the results.

I put the following together from suggestions I've seen, and it seems close but it's not working. A couple of points about it:

- When I run this, I get "C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\test\${subdir} does not exist."  (A subdirectory does exist, I have ...\test\testsub\xxx_xxx.dita)
- The target named "script" works perfectly by itself. If I point it to a folder, it transforms what's in it and gives me the result I need.
- In the `foreach` task if I change to just `<dirset dir=".">` as a test then the build succeeds, but it basically just runs the `"script"` target as is.
- In the target named "script", if I change `"*.dita"` to `"**\*.dita"` it then includes the top level folder in its operation so the result is not what I need, which is just to take each .dita file in each subfolder and wrap it in a folder of the same name as the dita file:

Starting state: `testsub\xxx_xxx.dita`

Desired result: `testsub\xxx_xxx\xxx_xxx.dita`

Scrambled result: `testsub\xxx_xxx\testsub\xxx_xxx.dita`

If anyone can tell me what's wrong with this (possibly many things) that would be great:

```
<project name="move_and_wrap_dita_topics" default="script" basedir="C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\test">

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
</taskdef>

<foreach target="script" param="worksheet" inheritall="true">
  <path>
      <dirset dir="${subDir}">
           <include name="*"/>
      </dirset>
  </path>
</foreach>

<target name="script">
   <copy todir="C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\cleaned" verbose="true">
     <fileset dir="C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\test">
        <include name="*.dita"/> 
     </fileset>
        <scriptmapper language="javascript">
   self.addMappedName(source.replace(source.split('.')[0], source.split('.')[0] + "/" + source.split('.')[0]));
      </scriptmapper>
  </copy>
</target>

</project>
```

As an alternative, if there's some way to just write the `"include name"` in the `"script"` task so that it skips the top folder completely and only rewrites starting at the subfolders, that would be even simpler. I've tried `<include name="/*.dita"/>`and all sorts of other variations but no luck.

Comment: Where are you defining the `subDir` property?

Comment: Ah right. I'm not. So, to define it as each subdir of a given top dir, how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting state: `testsub\xxx_xxx.dita`
>
> Desired result: `testsub\xxx_xxx\xxx_xxx.dita`

This should be doable with a single regex mapper, you don't need the `foreach` at all:

```
<copy todir="C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\cleaned" verbose="true">
  <fileset dir="C:\Developer\SVN\trunk\DITA\xxx_conversion\test"
           includes="*/*.dita" />
  <!-- use handledirsep to treat \ as if it were / in the source file name -->
  <regexpmapper handledirsep="true" from="^(.*)/([^/]*)\.dita$"
                to="\1/\2/\2.dita" />
</copy>
```

The `includes="*/*.dita"` will match `.dita` files that are one level below the base directory of the fileset, and the regex will convert `testsub/xxx.dita` in the source to `testsub/xxx/xxx.dita` in the destination.  If you want to find files that are one-or-more levels deep then use `*/**/*.dita` instead.

Comment: Great. I had tried a regex mapper but didn't get it to work, basically `handledirsep` and the exact wildcard setup were what I wasn't getting. Also the `$` in `.dita$` I think is important. Works perfectly. Thanks a million